# Integer as plus/minus combination of three squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Some time ago I came across the following statement in a paper:
"Every integer $k$ has a representation of the form
$k=\pm a^2 \pm b^2 \pm c^2$"
Unfortunately I can't remember where I read it, just wrote it down in my nodes. Moreover, I was not able to find this problem somewhere on the web. Now, I would be interested in a proof, and I suspect it might be rather easy, although I couldn't solve it.

Comment: $$k=2n+1 \implies k=(n+1)^2-n^2$$

$$k=2n \implies k=(n+1)^2-n^2-1^2$$

Comment: @Baconaro Wow I'm impressed!

Comment: @Baconaro  I think you should post that as a solution.  Hard to imagine a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$, we can write :
$pq = (\frac{p+q}{2})^2-(\frac{p-q}{2})^2$

With $p=1$ and $q=k$ or $q=k+1$

$$k=2n+1 \implies k=(n+1)^2−n^2$$
$$k=2n \implies k=(n+1)^2−n^2-1$$

Comment: As simple as that. Very nice. Thanks!